# How to pass a parameter to an inline javascript function

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to pass story_id into the innermost inline function, but its always 0 even though its not 0 in the outer function.  How do I pass this value in?

```
function activateSearch(){
  if($('story_filter')) Event.observe('story_filter', 'keyup',
    function(event) {
      $('stories_table').select(".story").each(
        function(story) {
          story_id = story.id.split('_')[1];
          story.select('.tableCell', '.indexCardContent').each(
            function(task, story_id) {
              hideStoryRow(story_id);
              task_filter = new RegExp($F('story_filter'), "i");
              if (task.innerHTML.match( task_filter ))
              {
                  showStoryRow(story_id);
                  throw $break;
              }
            }
          );
        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do to make this work is change this line:

```
    function(task, story_id) {
```

to this:

```
    function(task) {
```

You don't have to pass story_id anywhere -- it's already in scope in the inner function!

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The each method takes the function definition and then calls that function for each element in the Array. You'd need to write your own custom each method if you wanted to use the inline function definition.

For both readability and functionality, I would break out the inner most inline function and then for each element in the list, call out to your function.

Answer (score -1):

you've got a scoping issue.

quick fix: define story_id as a global.

```
var story_id;

function activateSearch() { ....
```

Comment: Variable `story_id` *is* already global, as it was introduced here without the `var` statement.

Comment: Would have been a better question if you had show that in your example code or explained that.